# Does Grails use Maven proxy settings?

Tags: maven, grails, proxy

I am very new to Grails, I am actually following the Getting Started documentation (https://docs.grails.org/4.0.10/guide/gettingStarted.html).

My question is: **does Grails in some way use or read Maven proxy setting?**

I managed to manually install Grails 4.0.10 in my Linux PC and the `grails -version` run fine, but when starting the `grails` shell I obtained a proxy error:

```
Error occurred running Grails CLI: status code: 502, reason phrase: Parent proxy unreacheable
```

Before covid lockdown I used my PC in an enterprice environment with a proxy, and I had a CNTLM listening at `localhost:3128`.

I suspected that in some script on my machine I forgot some proxy setting, but I cannot find any.

I tryed to use Grails version 4.0.9 and 3.3.11 but with the same results. I also tryed to install Grails via sdkman, but again I obtained the same error.

I then decided to use a virtual machine with a fresh installation and everything was OK.
While starting the first time I read some indication like "reading repository data", so I go to my Maven `~/.m2/settings.xml` file and commented out the proxy section (even though the proxy setting was not active):

```
    <proxies>
        <proxy>
            <id>cntlm-proxy</id>
            <active>false</active>
            <protocol>http</protocol>
            <host>127.0.0.1</host>
            <port>3128</port>
        </proxy>
    </proxies>
```

After commenting out the above section everything started to work fine, as like Grails war mis-reading the proxy configuration.

Did someone had my same problem or a similar one?

Comment: "After commenting out the above section everything started to work fine, as like Grails war mis-reading the proxy configuration." - It doesn't look like Grails was mis-reading the proxy config.  It looks like Grails was successfully reading it, and the proxy doesn't exist or can't be reached.  Is that what you are seeing?

Comment: @JeffScottBrown Yes, exactly. I wrote "mis-reading" because the Maven proxy setting was not enabled (`<active>false</active>`), and in fact I was not considering that setting, until I had a doubt...